# Splunk regex line breaker, combining multiple ERROR [stderr] lines into one event

Tags: java, regex, docker, logging, splunk

I am working on displaying logs from docker json-file in splunk. For the most part I have it working, except for when a stack trace is printed. I know `e.printStackTrace()` isn't best practice, but our services have a few here and there that I want to support in Splunk.

I am configuring the props.conf file, and I have the following `LINE_BREAKER` regex in props.conf.
`LINE_BREAKER=([\n\r]+)\s*{"log":"[0-9]+.*[0-9]\s+`

This will match up to the end of a timestamp of this form: `{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:18,796 ERROR [stderr] ...`

The problem is that the printed stack trace is coming in multiple lines like this:

```
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:18,796 ERROR [stderr] (default-threads - 3) java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:18.800485539Z"}
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:18,804 ERROR [stderr] (default-threads - 3) at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:18.806510971Z"}
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:19,259 ERROR [stderr] (default-threads - 3) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:19.264689098Z"}
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:19,259 ERROR [stderr] (default-threads - 3) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:19.281810119Z"}
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:19,274 ERROR [stderr] (default-threads - 3) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:19.28185714Z"}
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:19,275 ERROR [stderr] (default-threads - 3) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:19.281867696Z"}
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:19,275 ERROR [stderr] (default-threads - 3) at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:49)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:19.281875844Z"}
{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:19,498 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession] (default-threads - 3) error dispatching message: : javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-04-18T19:18:19.523359025Z"}
```

... and so on. until the end of the stack trace. Each line ends up being an event based on my regex for `LINE_BREAKER`, which is fine for `INFO` messages and single line `ERROR` messages from our logger, but not for the stack trace as above.

I want to combine this stack trace of the ERROR [stderr] together into one event. So my line break should match until the next timestamp message that is not [stderr].

from my example, it should match from the first line with `ERROR [stderr]` until: `{"log":"2019-04-18 15:18:19,498` (last log line above).

I have tried adding negative lookahead but now it will only match 1 time. `([\n\r]+)\s*{"log":"[0-9]+.*[0-9]\s+[\s\S]+\[(?!stderr])` matches until the last line, but if there are lines under that, none of them match anymore.

Comment: You will have better luck using actual program logic to do this instead of regex. Anyway, I wouldn't take any time to post an answer for someone who's asked 23 questions and not accepted any answers.

Comment: This is to integrate with Splunk the output of our logs. Of course, it's much simpler with program logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of the pattern `{"log":"[0-9]+.*[0-9]\s+` you are matching the timestamp part using `[0-9]+.*[0-9]\s+` can cause unnecessary bracktracking due to the `.*` which will first match until the end of the string.

You could make the timestamp like pattern more specific instead like `[0-9]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+`

To get the matches, one option could be to match the line containing `stderr`. Then repeat matching the following lines with that pattern 0+ times starting with a newline to combine them.

To keep matching the other lines you could make use of a negative lookahead after `ERROR` and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
^(?:{"log":"[0-9]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ ERROR \[stderr\].*(?:\n{"log":"[0-9]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ ERROR \[stderr\].*)*|{"log":"[0-9]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ ERROR (?!\[stderr\]).*)
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `{"log":"[0-9]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ ERROR \[stderr\].*`
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\n{"log":"[0-9]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ ERROR \[stderr\].*`
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
  - `|` Or
  - `{"log":"[0-9]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+ ERROR (?!\[stderr\]).*`
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/csAqzZ/1)